# Making two GPU's appear as one

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, sli, dual-gpu

I have two RTX 2080 GPU's and I'm trying to find the least path of resistance.

I'm training lots of AI models and I was wondering if it's possible to make multiple GPU's to show up as a single GPU.

Is this possible on Windows 10?

I swear I read somewhere that it's possible.

Comment: Do you already have your two cars bridged with SLI?

Comment: SLI or NVLINK? I've read that NVLINK is better for machine learning.

Answer (score 3):

Graphics cards have never been able to "appear as one" device.

For many years we have had [SLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Link_Interface) and its AMD counterpart [Crossfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_CrossFire) which used two or more graphics cards to render a single scene, but this requires a bit of hardware and a lot of software support.

In essence the software gives both cards an exactly identical set of data, runs the graphics card on different parts of the data, and then uses a special bridge between the two cards is used to transfer the results from one to the other where the result is pieced together.

At no point is the hardware of the two cards merged and used as a single card. It might look like it is what is happening from the outside but they do not appear or function as a single GPU, they are two cards working together.

Now this may be essentially what you want to do but there is an important distiction: your task most likely is not the use case for SLI software. SLI takes in graphics card draw calls (OpenGL or DirectX) and programs and outputs a patchwork of graphic cells and stitches them back together. It is a very specific use case with specific inputs and outputs.

Your AI modelling software may be roughly analogous, but your inputs are different, your interfaces to the graphics cards are different (OpenCL, etc instead of DirectX), and your outputs are not going to the same place. Your use case falls outside the use case for SLI and so you cannot use that particular software/hardware solution.

There may well be other software solutions to use multiple graphics cards together for various tasks and for that task, through that software, it may appear that you have only one device, but it will only work for that software.

There is no way to make two physical cards appear as one single physical device.

Comment: SLI/Crossfire works by giving each card equal amount of work.  Neither card could have more memory or be faster the the slowest card.  This was vastly different compared to multiple GPU support added to DX12.  In that case you have vastly different hardware and each card will be given as much work as it can handle.  There are cards that are two GPUs though but the RTX 2080 isn’t one of them.